# Equivalence of $I\Sigma_n$ and $I\Pi_n$

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

PA$^{-}\vdash I\Sigma_n \leftrightarrow I\Pi_n$.

Here $I\Sigma_n$ refers to the induction principle restricted to $\Sigma_n$ formulas. PA$^{-}$ is just PA without induction.

I was reading the paper by Paris and Kirby. In it they more or less give a one line proof for the above claim.

"Suppose $\theta(0) \wedge \forall x\ (\theta(x)\rightarrow\ \theta(x+1))$, but $\neg\theta(a)$, then induction also fails for $\exists w(a = y + w\ \wedge\ \neg\theta(w))$ and $\forall w(a = y + w\ \rightarrow\ \neg\theta(w))$"

I honestly have no idea what they are talking about here, hence if anyone could elaborate more on their reasoning I would deeply appreciate it.

Cheers

Comment: Start by computing the complexity of the final two formulas.

Comment: I think that the first line is a bit weird. It states that PA without the induction schema proves the induction schema for $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ formulas. That's probably a typo?

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are absolutely right, sorry about that. I edited and fix it, it should be "iff"

Comment: @some1fromhell Notice that $\neg \theta(x+1) \rightarrow \neg \theta(x)$ by contraposition. What they're trying to do is 'turn the interval around' by defining a $\phi(y)$ where $\phi(y) = \theta(a - y)$. Then induction fails for $\phi$. There are two basic ways to write this down formally, namely the authors' $\phi_1(y) \equiv \exists w$ etc, and $\phi_2(y) \equiv \forall w$ etc. Which one we actually use depends on whether $\theta$ is $\Sigma_n$ or $\Pi_n$.

Comment: Typo above: $\theta(a-y)$ should be $\neg \theta(a-y)$.